# Excel Formula - Not able to get the value from drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am working on an excel sheet with a drop-down list & I want to work around certain if-else conditions. Can you please have a look at the same. Thanking in advance.

Below is my excel sheet snapshot -

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is here -

```
=IF(AND(BF3="QA Completed",BU3="<>"),BU3-BA3, IF(AND(BF3="QA Completed",CU3="<>"),CU3-BA3,TODAY()-BA3))
```

Can you please guide me where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please write a complete question.

Comment: So what i want to achieve is - if column"QA status" is "QA Completed" and column "date assigned to IT" is "<place holder ie dd/mm/yy>" then column "days in ADDC" = "Date assigned to IT" - "Date Assiged"

Comment: if column"QA status" is "QA Completed" and column "date assigned to IT" is "<place holder ie dd/mm/yy>" then column "days in ADDC" = "Date assigned to IT" - "Date Assiged"  elseif "QA Status" does not equal to "QA Completed" then "days in ADDC" = Today()-"Date Assigned"

Comment: You need to look at how to use "and" op. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx

Comment: What is the value in column BU if there is no date? Is it "<>" as in your formula or is it "<place holder ie dd/mm/yy>" as in your description.

Answer (score 1):

Speculating that you may want

```
=IF(AND(BF3="QA Completed",ISNUMBER(BU3)),BU3-BA3, IF(AND(BF3="QA Completed",ISNUMBER(CU3)),CU3-BA3,TODAY()-BA3))
```

The formula will check if the cells BU3 and CU3 contain a number. Dates are numbers, formatted as dates. You can use data validation to ensure the numbers are dates within a specific time frame. So, if BU3 contains a number and the status in BF is met, then calculate BU3-BA3. Otherwise, if CU3 contains a number, calculate CU3-BA3. If neither cell contains a number, calculate Today-BA3.